# Auth::id() utilizando ajax devuelve null Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, datatables

Sucede que muestro en un `DataTable` un contenido y haciendo la configuración pertinente para que se me muestre solo el contenido del usuario logueado por lo que utilizo un método en mi controlador que me devuelve los registros asociados al usuario que se encuentra logueado.

```
    Por ejemplo:
    $revision = Revision::where('id', Auth::id());
    ...
```

Resulta que esta consulta no me devuelve ningún registro si se lo paso de esa manera porque me devuelve `null`, pensaba que no funcionaba hasta que le pase un numero para comprobar, y si me mostró los registros de ese usuario, y todo esto a través del plugin `DataTable` haciendo uso de ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto

```
Auth::user()->id
```

Comment: Auth::user()->id, Auth::id(), auth()->user()->id y auth()->id(), todos devuelven el id del usuario logueado pero al utilizarlo con ajax como explico arriba me devuelve null

Comment: Si pones el código completo estaría estupendo.